# How to make nginx-docker container running always

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to run a docker container for nginx providing reverse-proxy.

The command I am trying is:

```
docker run --name nginx-proxy -p 80:80 -v ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -v ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx -d nginx
```

but it stops immediately after started. Result of docker ps -a is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                  NAMES
89b3526e2c25        nginx                       "nginx -g 'daemon off"   11 seconds ago      Exited (1) 10 seconds ago                             nginx-proxy
```

How can I make this container always running?

Comment: please provide logs
docker logs 89b3526e2c25

Comment: You pointed me to right direction. There were several issues(e.g. nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration) in my nginx.conf file. docker logs provided hints on those errors. Now its running fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use upstart or sustemd.

This link to official website documentation

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/

Answer (score 1):

I saw incorrect syntax here "nginx -g **'daemon off**". You can try to edit the command or rebuild Dockerfile with ENTRYPOINT like `["nginx", "-g", "daemon off"]`

Another way, add the line below to nginx.conf before build Dockerfile.

`RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: It's the default nginx image, I didn't change anything. now its running fine after fixing nginx.conf.